# In Asp Net Mvc How Can I Post Model To Controller With Pagedlist And Select All With Checkboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post, pagedlist

I want to list all items in a page developed in asp.net mvc with pagedlist. it is done. I want to update all or selected items. can be listed and can select only selected items but can not post the model to controller. after Update button I can post model but not with values, it is empty.can anyone help?

My controller:

```
namespace Management.Controllers
{   
    public ActionResult ListDebts(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, 
        string searchString, string Part,string Term, string PayStat, int? page, bool? checkboxes)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.PartSortList = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.DueDateSortList = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
        ViewBag.AmountSortList = sortOrder == "Amount" ? "amount_desc" : "Amount";
        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        var debts = from d in db.Debts
                       select d;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            debts = debts.Where(d => d.DebtPart.PartitionName.Equals(searchString));
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Part))
        {
            debts = debts.Where(d => d.DebtPart.PartitionName.Equals(Part));
            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = Part;
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Term))
        {
            debts = debts.Where(d => d.DebtTerm.Equals(Term));
            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = Term;
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                debts = debts.OrderByDescending(d => d.DebtPart.PartitionName);
                break;
            case "Date":
                debts = debts.OrderBy(d => d.DebtDueDate);
                break;
            case "date_desc":
                debts = debts.OrderByDescending(d => d.DebtDueDate);
                break;
            case "Amount":
                debts = debts.OrderBy(d => d.DebtAmount);
                break;
            case "amount_desc":
                debts = debts.OrderByDescending(d => d.DebtAmount);
                break;
            default:  // Name ascending 
                debts= debts.OrderBy(d=>d.DebtDueDate);
                break;
        }

        List<SelectDebtEditorViewModel> model = new List<SelectDebtEditorViewModel>();

        foreach (var item in debts)
        {
            var editorViewModel = new SelectDebtEditorViewModel()
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                DebtPart = item.DebtPart,
                DebtIsFixture = item.DebtIsFixture,
                DebtTerm = item.DebtTerm,
                DebtAmount = item.DebtAmount,
                DebtDueDate = item.DebtDueDate,
                DebtIsPaid = item.DebtIsPaid,
                Selected = false
            };
            model.Add(editorViewModel);
        }

        int pageSize = 20;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(model.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }

    public ActionResult Aaa(SelectDebtEditorViewModel model)
    {
        if (model != null)
        {
            return Json("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("An Error Has occoured");
        }
    }
}
```

My models:

```
namespace Management.Models
{ 
    public class SelectDebtEditorViewModel
    {
        public bool Selected { get; set; } 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DebtTerm { get; set; }     
        public DebtTypes DebtType { get; set; }  
        public decimal DebtAmount { get; set; }  
        public CurrencyType DebtCurrency { get; set; }   
        public YesNoTypes DebtIsFixture { get; set; }
        public DateTime DebtDueDate { get; set; }    
        public PaymentTypes DebtIsPaid { get; set; }
        public decimal DebtRemainAmount { get; set; }    
        public DateTime RecordDate { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual Partition DebtPart { get; set; }
    }

    public class DebtSelectionViewModel
    {
        public List<SelectDebtEditorViewModel> Debt { get; set; }
        public DebtSelectionViewModel()
        {
            this.Debt = new List<SelectDebtEditorViewModel>();
        }    
        public IEnumerable<int> getSelectedIds()
        {           
            return (from d in this.Debt where d.Selected select d.Id).ToList();
        }
    }

}
```

And Debt.cs

```
namespace Management.Data.Financial
{
    public enum CurrencyType
    {
        TL = 1
    }       
    public enum DebtTypes
    {
        Income = 1
    }
    public enum YesNoTypes
    {
        Yes= 1,
        No = 2
    }
    public enum PaymentTypes
    {
        Paid = 1,
        NotPaid = 2,
        NotAllPaid = 3
    }
    public class Debt
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }     
        public string DebtTerm { get; set; }     
        public DebtTypes DebtType { get; set; }         
        public decimal DebtAmount { get; set; }        
        public CurrencyType DebtCurrency { get; set; }   
        public YesNoTypes DebtIsFixture { get; set; }    
        public DateTime DebtDueDate { get; set; }           
        public PaymentTypes DebtIsPaid { get; set; }
        public decimal DebtRemainAmount { get; set; }    
        public DateTime RecordDate { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual Partition DebtPart { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My view;

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Management.Models.SelectDebtEditorViewModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Income List";
}

<h2>Income List</h2>
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@section scripts{
    <style type="text/css">         
        input[type="text"] {
            width: 150px;
        }
    </style>


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var arr = [];

        function toggleChecked(status) {
            $("#checkboxes input").each(function () {
                $(this).prop("checked", status);
                checkboxcontrol(status);
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#checkall").prop('checked', false);
            $("#checkall").click(function () {
                var status = $("#checkall").prop('checked');
                toggleChecked(status);
            });
        });

        function checkboxcontrol(status) {

            var itemValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if (status) {
                arr.push(status);
            }
            else {
                arr.shift();
            }
        }


        $("#checkboxes input").change(function () {       
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {      
                checkboxcontrol(true);      
            }
            else {        
                checkboxcontrol(false);          
            }       
        });

        $("#btnUpdate").click(function (event) {
            if (arr.length<=0) {
                alert("No record selected.");
                event.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
            if (!confirm("You will update are you sure?")) {

                event.preventDefault();
                return;
            }

            var jsonObj = $("#frame").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("Aaa")",
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
                dataType: "json",
                type: "post",
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
            callAjax(arr.join(","));
        });
    </script>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("ListDebts", "Financial", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-horizontal", encType = "multipart/form-data", role = "form", id = "frame" , name="frame"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Part No : ", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBox("Part", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Income Term: ", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBox("Term", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Pay Status : ", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBox("PayStat", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="List" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkall" /><span>  Select All</span>
        </div>

        <div id="checkboxes">
        <table class="table" id="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Seç
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Part", "ListDebts", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.PartSortList, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                </th>
                <th>
                    Fixture
                </th>
                <th>
                    Income term
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Amount", "ListDebts", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.AmountSortList, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Due Date", "ListDebts", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DueDateSortList, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                </th>
                <th>
                    PAY Status
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DebtPart.PartitionName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DebtIsFixture)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DebtTerm)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DebtAmount) TL
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DebtDueDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DebtIsPaid)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>


            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Update"
                           id="btnUpdate" />

                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<hr />
<br />
}

Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) / @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("ListDebts",
new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

---

My controller:

```
namespace Management.Controllers
{   
    public ActionResult ListDebts(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, 
        string searchString, string Part,string Term, string PayStat, int? page, bool? checkboxes)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.PartSortList = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.DueDateSortList = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
        ViewBag.AmountSortList = sortOrder == "Amount" ? "amount_desc" : "Amount";
        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        var debts = from d in db.Debts
                       select d;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            debts = debts.Where(d => d.DebtPart.PartitionName.Equals(searchString));
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Part))
        {
            debts = debts.Where(d => d.DebtPart.PartitionName.Equals(Part));
            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = Part;
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Term))
        {
            debts = debts.Where(d => d.DebtTerm.Equals(Term));
            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = Term;
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                debts = debts.OrderByDescending(d => d.DebtPart.PartitionName);
                break;
            case "Date":
                debts = debts.OrderBy(d => d.DebtDueDate);
                break;
            case "date_desc":
                debts = debts.OrderByDescending(d => d.DebtDueDate);
                break;
            case "Amount":
                debts = debts.OrderBy(d => d.DebtAmount);
                break;
            case "amount_desc":
                debts = debts.OrderByDescending(d => d.DebtAmount);
                break;
            default:  // Name ascending 
                debts= debts.OrderBy(d=>d.DebtDueDate);
                break;
        }

        List<SelectDebtEditorViewModel> model = new List<SelectDebtEditorViewModel>();

        foreach (var item in debts)
        {
            var editorViewModel = new SelectDebtEditorViewModel()
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                DebtPart = item.DebtPart,
                DebtIsFixture = item.DebtIsFixture,
                DebtTerm = item.DebtTerm,
                DebtAmount = item.DebtAmount,
                DebtDueDate = item.DebtDueDate,
                DebtIsPaid = item.DebtIsPaid,
                Selected = false
            };
            model.Add(editorViewModel);
        }

        int pageSize = 20;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(model.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }

    public ActionResult Aaa(SelectDebtEditorViewModel model)
    {
        if (model != null)
        {
            return Json("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("An Error Has occoured");
        }
    }
}
```

My models:

```
namespace Management.Models
{ 
    public class SelectDebtEditorViewModel
    {
        public bool Selected { get; set; } 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DebtTerm { get; set; }     
        public DebtTypes DebtType { get; set; }  
        public decimal DebtAmount { get; set; }  
        public CurrencyType DebtCurrency { get; set; }   
        public YesNoTypes DebtIsFixture { get; set; }
        public DateTime DebtDueDate { get; set; }    
        public PaymentTypes DebtIsPaid { get; set; }
        public decimal DebtRemainAmount { get; set; }    
        public DateTime RecordDate { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual Partition DebtPart { get; set; }
    }

    public class DebtSelectionViewModel
    {
        public List<SelectDebtEditorViewModel> Debt { get; set; }
        public DebtSelectionViewModel()
        {
            this.Debt = new List<SelectDebtEditorViewModel>();
        }    
        public IEnumerable<int> getSelectedIds()
        {           
            return (from d in this.Debt where d.Selected select d.Id).ToList();
        }
    }

}
```

And Debt.cs

```
namespace Management.Data.Financial
{
    public enum CurrencyType
    {
        TL = 1
    }       
    public enum DebtTypes
    {
        Income = 1
    }
    public enum YesNoTypes
    {
        Yes= 1,
        No = 2
    }
    public enum PaymentTypes
    {
        Paid = 1,
        NotPaid = 2,
        NotAllPaid = 3
    }
    public class Debt
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }     
        public string DebtTerm { get; set; }     
        public DebtTypes DebtType { get; set; }         
        public decimal DebtAmount { get; set; }        
        public CurrencyType DebtCurrency { get; set; }   
        public YesNoTypes DebtIsFixture { get; set; }    
        public DateTime DebtDueDate { get; set; }           
        public PaymentTypes DebtIsPaid { get; set; }
        public decimal DebtRemainAmount { get; set; }    
        public DateTime RecordDate { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual Partition DebtPart { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code plz. View and controller where you try to post

Comment: I posted code below.

Comment: you should update question with code, not write it as answer, it's not forum

Comment: Sorry, I am new here.do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: too many code. What controller method get empty records? And where is the string in View that renders this Checkboxes?

Comment: ok. i will solve it by webgrid.